# Can the Hermitian operator be related to state space to describe physical phenomena?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, quantum-information

Can space-time, in which phenomena occur, and the space of states in which phenomena are described by means of the Hermitian operator be related? I suspect it is because the hermetic operator is built on linear spaces that associate real states with vectors, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You mean, how do you represent hermitian operators in Hilbert space in terms of coordinate space functions, or, even, phase-space functions serving as convolution kernels?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes. Thank you very much for clarifying. Can you also recommend bibliography?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Dirac bra-ket  coordinate picture is
$$ H=\iint\!\! dx dx'~|x\rangle \langle x|H|x'\rangle\langle x'| ~~~\leadsto ,   
$$
so that, considering $\langle x|\psi\rangle =\psi(x)$ and $h(x,x')= \langle x|H|x'\rangle$,  you readily  have
$$
|\phi\rangle =H|\psi \rangle ~~~\leftrightarrow ~~~\phi(x)= \int \!\!   dx' ~~h(x,x') \psi (x').
$$

That is, you *represent* Hilbert-space states and operators through coordinate-space functions and convolutions.

---

Beyond this, there is a much subtler and disparate formulation which maps Hilbert-space operators to
phase-space functions, through the [Wigner map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Weyl_transform#The_inverse_map). This  undergirds a qualitatively, distinctly *different* [formulation of QM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation), equivalent to the Hilbert space you are studying, but I suspect this outranges your scope. In this formulation, the phase-space convolution law is very-very-very different, and is called the "star product".

Comment: Thank you! it helped me to have things a little clearer :)